# Creating array-like objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In JavaScript, there are objects that pretend to be arrays (or are "array-like").  Such objects are `arguments`, `NodeList`s (returned from `getElementsByClassName`, etc.), and jQuery objects.

When `console.log`ged, they appear as arrays, but they are not.  I know that in order to be array-like, an object must have a `length` property.

So I made an "object" like this:

```
function foo(){
    this.length = 1;
    this[0] = "bar";
}

var test = new foo;
```

When I `console log(test)`, I get (as expected) a `foo` object.  I can "convert" it to an array using

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(test)
```

But, I don't want to convert it, I want it to be array-like. How do I make an array-like object, so that when it's `console.log`ged, it appears as an array?

I tried setting `foo.prototype = Array.prototype`, but `console.log(new foo)` still shows a `foo` object, and not an array.

Comment: *"How do I make an array-like object, so that when it's console.logged, it appears as an array?"* Just because a console isn't displaying it using Array literal syntax, or some other syntax that makes you think of an Array, doesn't mean it isn't *"array-like"*. How a console displays your data has no bearing on what that data is.

Comment: @amnotiam, while that is true, it's a case where I've found it useful to assist the console in assisting me. When I log an "array-like" object, I don't really care that much about the object as much as its contents.

Comment: @amnotiam: I was just kinda curious how jQuery objects and `arguments` worked.  I wanted to know why they are logged as arrays. :-P

Comment: @zzzzBov: I don't disagree with that. I'm just saying there's a distinction between having an "array-like object", and how some console displays that object.

Comment: @Rocket: I understand that. But it's not how jQuery objects or `arguments` works. It's how various consoles work, which may be different from each other. Perhaps I misinterpreted your sentence above a bit.

Comment: @amnotiam: No, you're right.  I didn't realize it was just the console doing that.  I thought it was something special in the object itself.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depends specifically on the console. For custom objects in Chrome's developer console, and Firebug you'll need both the `length` and `splice` properties. `splice` will also have to be a function.

```
a = {
    length: 0,
    splice: function () {}
}
console.log(a); //[]
```

It's important to note, however, that there is no official standard.

The following code is used by jQuery (v1.11.1) internally to determine if an object should use a `for` loop or a `for..in` loop:

```
function isArraylike( obj ) {
    var length = obj.length,
        type = jQuery.type( obj );

    if ( type === "function" || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( obj.nodeType === 1 && length ) {
        return true;
    }

    return type === "array" || length === 0 ||
        typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj;
}
```

Note that it's possible to have an object that appears in the console as an array (`[]`) but that gets iterated over with a `for..in` loop in jQuery, or an object that appears as an object in the console (`{}`) but that gets iterated over with a `for` loop in jQuery.

Comment: Neat!  Adding the `splice` property *did* show it as an array!

Comment: @Rocket, it's why jQuery objects look like arrays in the console, even though they don't inherit from `Array`.

Comment: Then how is `arguments.splice` set to `undefined`?

Comment: Anyway, its just an illusion of `console` implementations. Afterall, there is **no** `Array` in ECMAscript (when we forget about TypedArrays).

Comment: @Rocket, type checking for specific types was used in Firebug. I don't know what chrome uses. For custom consoles, you could check for `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Arguments]'` in some browsers.

Comment: @jAndy: What do you mean? `Array` is specified by ECMAScript.

Comment: @TimDown: I'm saying that the specified `Array` also just inherits from `Object` with some sugar on top. So actually, a `console` object should treat both the same on logging those things.

Comment: It is egregious that functions and `window` are array-like. The length property on them makes no sense.

Answer (score 5):

The same question got into my mind as while we can use array like `arguments` parameter:

```js
function arrayLike() {
  console.log(typeof arguments)
  console.log(arguments)
  console.log(Array.from(arguments))
}
arrayLike(1,2,3)
```

So, let's try creating our own array-like object:

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
  0: 1,
  1: 2
 }
 
 console.log(Array.from(arrayLikeObject))
```

Obviously, there's no length property defined so our `arrayLikeObject` will only return an empty array. Now, let's try defining a length property:

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
  length: 2,
  0: 1,
  1: 2
 }
 
 console.log(Array.from(arrayLikeObject))
```

What if length is set different?

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
  length: 1,
  0: 1,
  1: 2
 }
 
 console.log(Array.from(arrayLikeObject))
 // it will only return the value from first `0: 1`
```

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
  length: 5,
  0: 1,
  1: 2
 }
 
 console.log(Array.from(arrayLikeObject))
 // other 3 values will be printed as undefined
```

---

> But, I don't want to convert it...

You actually wanted to create an array, not array-like object. The array-like object must be converted like you said:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLikeObject)
// Or,
[].slice.call(arrayLikeObject)
```

If you do try to use array methods on array-like object, then you'll get type error:

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
  length: 5,
  0: 1,
  1: 2
 }

 console.log(arrayLikeObject.sort())
```

Thus, to use the array methods on arrayLikeObject, we need to convert it into array as we did in preceding examples using `Array.from`.

Otherwise, you simply need to create an array:

```
let arr = [1,2] // I don't mean, you don't know
```

---

Other consideration:

You can't use it as constructor:

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
    length: 1,
    slice: function () {
      return 1
    }
}

console.log(new arrayLikeObject) // Type error
```

In the following snippet, the result will be `[undefined]` as the length property is set to 1 but there's no `0` indexed property:

```js
let arrayLikeObject = {
  length: 1,
  slice: function () {
    return 1
  }
}
console.log(Array.from(arrayLikeObject))
```

But if you set the length to 0, then the result will be an empty array `[]` because we're telling that we don't have any values in this array-like object.

Comment: glad you get it helpful

Answer (score 3):

Is this any use: [extended array prototype](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2009/04/13/javascript-and-the-extended-array-prototype), seems like he's doing what you did and creating the prototype as an array, but including an extra method (that may or may not work, I've not tested this):

```
var MyArray = function() {
};

MyArray.prototype = new Array;

MyArray.prototype.forEach = function(action) {
    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l, ++i) {
        action(this[i]);
    }
};
```

Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: That adds all the functions from `Array.prototype` to `MyArray`, but with `arguments` and jQuery objects, they don't have those.

Comment: this also adds `enumerable` property `forEach`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this :

```
var ArrayLike = (function () {

 var result;

 function ArrayLike(n) {

     for (var idx = 0; idx < n; idx++) {
         this[idx] = idx + 1;
     }

     // this.length = Array.prototype.length; THIS WILL NOT WORK !

 }


 // ArrayLike.prototype.splice = Array.prototype.splice; THIS WILL NOT WORK !


 // THIS WILL WORK !
 Object.defineProperty(ArrayLike.prototype, 'length', {

     get: function() {

         var count = 0, idx = 0;

         while(this[idx]) {
             count++;
             idx++;
         }
         return count;

     }

 });


 ArrayLike.prototype.splice = Array.prototype.splice;


 ArrayLike.prototype.multiple = function () {

     for (var idx = 0 ; idx < this.length ; idx++) {

         if (result) {
             result = result * this[idx];
         } else {
             result = this[idx];
         }
     }

     return result;
 };

 return ArrayLike
 })();

var al = new ArrayLike(5);

al.__proto__ = ArrayLike.prototype;

console.log(al.length, al.multiple(), al);
```

This will display in Chrome : 5 120 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: Won't the length property fail to give a correct result if any element of the array is falsy?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is what you are looking for.
Override the toString function.

```
foo.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return "[object Foo <" + this[0] +">]";
}
```

Comment: Not quite.  What I want is when you `console.log` it, it displays like an array `[]`.  In Chrome, when you `console.log(arguments)` it's looks like an array, but it's really not.