# Jquery selectors don't work for assigning dom element to variable

Tags: jquery

I have a program that assigns a variable as:

```
var theList = document.getElementById('theList');
```

it uses jquery, but if I write it like this:

```
var theList = $('#theList');
```

the function that uses that variable doesn't work.

What is the distinction between a jquery selector and using getElementById?

Comment: You'd want to use `theList = $('#theList')[0]` or `theList = $('#theList').get(0)`.

Answer (score 18):

`document.getElementById`  returns a native DOM Element object, with direct access to that node's properties.

jQuery functions instead return "jQuery collections", i.e a jQuery object with an associated set of functions / plugins, etc that acts like an array of DOM nodes.

A common convention used to tell the former from the latter is to prefix variables containing the latter with `$`:

To extract the individual elements from a jQuery collection as DOM nodes, either use `.get(n)` or `[n]`.

```
var $theList = $('#theList');   // jQuery collection
var theList = $theList[0];      // DOM node
var theList = $theList.get(0);  // also a DOM node
```

Attribute and property access depends on whether you have a jQuery collection or not:

```
var id = $theList.attr('id');   // jQuery function
var id = theList.id;            // native property
```

Comment: After searching "DOM element vs jQuery object" I came across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element and determined that the jquery equivalent of var theList = document.getElementById('theList'); would be var theList = $('#theList').get(0);

Comment: @user1469779 yes, that says much the same.

Comment: Exactly the code I gave in my question to do the conversion. Good to see you managed to do an edit to include the conversion process.

Answer (score 1):

The first `theList` is a DOM element; the second `theList` (which would ideally be written as `$theList`) is a [jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/). Your function is apparently expecting the former and not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

That's because $('#theList') returns a JQuery Object, not a DOM Object. JQuery objects do not have the same methods & properties as a Javascript Element/Node might.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` function returns first element with given id where jquery selector returns object known as the "wrapped set". You can use `each` function to iterate through it and call your function.

See this article: http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/40923.

Answer (score -1):

The standard getElementByID function returns a JavaScript reference to the DOM element, whereas the jQuery function returns a jQuery object (which contains an array-like structure of references to zero or more JavaScript references to DOM elements).

To make them compatible you can use:

```
var theList = $('#theList').get(0);
```

NB: Edited to help keep world peace and correct my hastily typed terminology that commenters were quick to point out.

Comment: no, it's really not "an array of jQuery objects".  It's a single jQuery object with a set of numerically indexed properties representing the individual DOM elements within that collection.

Comment: It's not a "JavaScript object", it's a DOM element. jQuery doesn't produce an array, although it's [array-like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11886626/497418).

Comment: Depends how you look at it.. a jQuery object contains a list structure of individual objects or refers to a single jQuery object if only one item is returned by the selector. If you do jQuery('.everything') you get not one object but a list of objects.

Comment: No, it's not how you look at it. Arrays are produced via array literals (`[]`), or the `Array` constructor function. Everything else is *not* an array. Yes, it may be a collection, but `array != collection`.

Comment: yes, but those "objects" are "native DOM elements", not "JavaScript Objects" and certainly not nested "jQuery objects".

Comment: Yes, the plain JS function returns a DOM element and the jQuery object contains a potential array structure. I've already edited my hastily typed post, try to get over it.