# javascript getter on private variables

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to create a getter on the following:

```
function Field(val){
    this.value = {};
}

Field.prototype = {
    get value(){
        return this._value;
    },
    set value(val){
        this._value = val;
    }
};
```

But what I was able to achieve is a getter for `field.value`

I want to achieve something like this:

```
field.value.foo['20'] = 'some_value'; // ==> Setter
field.value.foo['20']; // 'some_value' ==> Getter
```

But I was not able to achieve this, using the above code .. Can someone help ..

Comment: Initialize the container as `this.value = {foo: {}};`?

Comment: Are all your indices integer?  You could make your object [array-like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886578/creating-array-like-objects-in-javascript).

Comment: @Emissary This wouldn't achieve the desired goal : make the values private.

Comment: @dystroy There's not really any such thing is *JS* though - if it's private just don't use it... if that's the requirement the solution may as well be "pick a convention".

Comment: @Emissary There is (see my answer). Not available in most browsers yet, though.

Comment: @dystroy I seen your answer but realistically how long before it's actually seen in common usage?

Comment: @Emissary Depends. JavaScript is used a lot server side and node.js already did integrate a lot of harmony features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually solve this in ES5. I'm documenting this here, for other users to help gain from it..

```
function Foo() {
    this.__value__ = {};
    this.__value__['20'] = 'some_value';
};

Foo.prototype.__defineGetter__('foo', function() {
    return this.__value__;
});

function Field() {
    this.__value__ = new Foo();
};

Field.prototype.__defineGetter__('value', function() {
    return this.__value__;
});
```

Now, to test this ..

```
var field = new Field();
var value = field.value.foo['20'];
console.log(value);
```

I've updated a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8u6Zz/1/)

Comment: Don't use this ! You forgot [the big warning from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter) : *Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.*

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a generic getter/setter, able to change any property of your `value` object.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with the current version of ECMAScript, you'll have to wait for [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which should be available with ECMAScript 6 (and are available in the last gecko).

See [ES6 wiki for direct proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies).

In the meanwhile, there's probably a solution with the current state of JavaScript for your real problem.

Comment: Can you please shed some light, on "solution with the current state of JavaScript" ?

Comment: @user3216499 "for your real problem". I mean : what you precisely ask for isn't possible in most browsers yet, so you need to start from **why** do you want to do this and look for another design.