# array.eq() vs. array[] in Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slideshow

When accessing an array, when is it appropriate to use the .eq() function?

For example, I have...

```
slides.eq(slidesLength-1).css("z-index", (slidesLength-1));
```

and later I have...

```
for(i=0; i<slidesLength-1; i++) {
    $(slides[i]).css("left", "-100%");
}
```

In the first piece of code, the slideshow stops functioning if I don's use the .eq() function. However, the second piece seems to function whether I use the .eq() function or not. Why is this?

Answer (score 7):

`slides` is *not* an array.  It's a jQuery object.  The [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method returns you the element at the specified index as a *jQuery object*.

While jQuery objects may not be arrays, they can *pretend* to be by having a `length` property as well as properties corresponding to the indexes.  (Since they are not arrays, you can't call methods like `.pop()`, `.forEach()`, etc. on them.)

When you do `slides[i]`, you are actually getting the *DOM element*, not a jQuery object.  The `$()` function turns the DOM element into a jQuery object.

So, when you do `slides.eq(1)`, internally jQuery is doing `$(slides[i])`.

P.S. Objects, like jQuery objects, that pretend to be arrays are called "array-like objects".  If you `console.log(slides)`, it may look like an array.  This is just your console trying to make things convenient for you.  (See this question for more info: [Creating array-like objects in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11886578/206403))

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. It's clear I need to do some further reading.

Answer (score 5):

`.eq()` is a jQuery method which returns a jQuery object, while accessing by index returns plain DOM element. You should use `eq()` when you want to use jQuery methods (`css()` in this case) on the returned selection.

The reason `$(slides[i])` works is because you're constructing a jQuery object by passing the plain element to `$()` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the difference now. I'll be sure to read more about the nuances.

Answer (score 4):

Your `slides` variable is not an `Array`, but a jQuery object.

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns a jQuery object, eventually empty if `index` is out of bounds, and a negative `index` is counted from the end.

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a DOM Element, or `undefined` if `index` is out of bounds, and a negative `index` is counted from the end.

`[]` returns a DOM Element, or throw an Error if `index` is out of bounds.

...

Additionally, jQuery methods let you interact with a set of elements as it was alone. So you if you do:

```
slides.css("left", "-100%");
```

It is applied on every matched elements contained in the jQuery object. It is unnecessary to loop over them.

...

Also the preferred way to loop over matched elements is using the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method:

```
slides.each(function (i, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
});
```

...

Also it is an established convention to prefix jQuery variables with a `$` sign; it let you to easily differentiate DOM elements from jQuery objects. But that's only a matter of taste.

Comment: Good answer... I forgot about the `.get()` method!

Comment: Note: If you call `.get()` without a parameter on a jQuery object, you will be returned an [actual] array (of DOM elements or whatever was in the jQuery object).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I'll be sure to integrate your answer into my code.

Comment: Ok, right now I'm using a for loop and you're suggesting using the .each() function. Can the .each() function target all but one element contained within my jQuery object?